# Unable to successfully import Text.Regex.Posix in Stack project

Tags: regex, haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I'm trying to use the `=~` function in a Haskell source file.
I've installed the `Text.Regex.Posix` package using `stack` (`stack install regex-posix-0.96.0.0`) and added it in the `extra-deps` array of my `stack.yaml` file:

`stack.yaml`:

```yaml
resolver: lts-15.5
packages:
- .
extra-deps:
  - regex-posix-0.96.0.0
```

in my Haskell source file, I'm importing the `Text.Regex.Posix` as follows:

```hs
module Lib (
 someFunc
) where

import Text.Regex.Posix

someFunc :: String -> Bool
someFunc str = str =~ "myregex"
```

but then, running `stack ghci` I get the following error:

```
    Could not load module ‘Text.Regex.Posix’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘regex-posix-0.96.0.0’.
    You can run ‘:set -package regex-posix’ to expose it.
    (Note: this unloads all the modules in the current scope.)
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
5 | import Text.Regex.Posix
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How do I expose the `=~` function?
thanks!

Comment: Do you have a cabal file? Did you add it there?

Comment: Does the code compile? What happens when you run `stack build` instead of `stack ghci`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare it as a dependency of your package by adding it to build-depends in your package.yaml or .cabal file.

You don’t need to mention it in extra-deps since it’s in lts-15.

Comment: Thank you Simon! I've previously added it to the Cabal file, but reverted the change because of the alert saying that "I have manually modified the Cabal file", so I thought there was a way to make it work only modifying the stack.yaml file.

Comment: When you have a package.yaml file, you should make your changes there, and let stack itself update the cabal file when it does a build. (Or, you can delete the package.yaml file entirely, then you won't get the warning.)